# How to append Label dynamically to StackLayout in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on xamarin forms where trying to add Menus and submenus dynamically. I am able to bind all main menu successfully. Now I am trying to add a submenu, I saw some article how to add a submenu, I got to know that I should make use of Grouping, the problem with grouping is it will add at least one submenu to each main menu. So I thought to create one label If submenu exists append to the label. How to do it?

The label is inside of ListView.ItemTemplate. Just after the main menu if it has submenu I need to bind in the label.

My XAML file

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout Padding="15,10" x:Name="submenu"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
           <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="24"/>
           //Here i need to append label if it has submenu
          </StackLayout>
       </ViewCell>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

C# Code

```
public ObservableCollection<LayoutPageMenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
List<LayoutPageMenuItem> layoutPageMenuItems = new List<LayoutPageMenuItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < Menus.AllMenus.Count; i++)
{
     var layoutPageMenuItem = new LayoutPageMenuItem();
     if (Menus.AllMenus[i].IsSubMenu == false && Menus.AllMenus[i].ParentMenuId == "" || Menus.AllMenus[i].ParentMenuId == null)
      {
          layoutPageMenuItem.Id = Menus.AllMenus[i].MenuId;
          layoutPageMenuItem.Title = Menus.AllMenus[i].MenuName;
          layoutPageMenuItems.Add(layoutPageMenuItem);
      }
    else
     {
         var Submenu = new Label { Text = Menus.AllMenus[i].MenuName };                     
     }
}

MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<LayoutPageMenuItem>(layoutPageMenuItems);
```

Comment: Are you using MVVM or not?

Comment: No, I am not following MVVM @G.hakim

Comment: I suggest that you can add the label in advance and set the isvisible as false.When it has a submenu,set the value as true.